# best way to get data from dict

Tags: python

I have a function `general_statistics` that takes a dict as input and get the wanted information. the function is working without any problem, but I want to know if I can do it with a pythonic way because I'm trying to improve my skills.

```
def general_statistics(input_data: dict):
        result = {}
        if 'general' in input_data.keys():
            if bool(input_data['general']):
                result['name'] = input_data['general']['name']
                result['information'] = input_data['general']['information']
                result['date'] = input_data['general']['creation_date']
                result['adress'] = input_data['general']['adress']
                if 'two' in input_data['general']['photo'].keys():
                    result['picture_person'] = input_data['general']['photo']['two']['ids']
                else:
                    result['picture_person'] = input_data['general']['photo']['one']['ids']
                if 'phones' in input_data['general'].keys():
                    result['phones'] = input_data['general']['phones']
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                result['name'] = ''
                result['information'] = ''
                result['date'] = ''
                result['adress'] = ''
        else:
            result['name'] = ''
            result['information'] = ''
            result['date'] = ''
            result['adress'] = ''
        if 'intrest' in input_data.keys():
            if bool(input_data['intrest']):
                intrest_list = []
                for gender in input_data['intrest']['gender_type']:
                    intrest_list.append(gender.split('/')[-1])
                    result['genders'] = intrest_list
        else:
            result['genders'] = []
        if 'command_details' in input_data.keys():
            if bool(input_data['command_details']):
                result['shiping'] = input_data['command_details']['shiping']
        else:
            result['shiping'] = ''
        if 'command_statistics' in input_data.keys():
            if bool(input_data['command_statistics']):
                result['com_statistics'] = input_data['command_statistics']
            else:
                command_statistics = {}
                command_statistics['count'] = ''
                command_statistics['items'] = ''
                command_statistics['payed'] = ''
                command_statistics['unpayed'] = ''
                result['com_statistics'] = command_statistics
        else:
            command_statistics = {}
            command_statistics['count'] = ''
            command_statistics['items'] = ''
            command_statistics['payed'] = ''
            command_statistics['unpayed'] = ''
            result['com_statistics'] = command_statistics

        result['com_statistics'] = input_data['command_statistics']
        if 'receiver_info' in input_data.keys():
            if bool(input_data['receiver_info']):
                if 'general' in input_data['receiver_info'].keys():
                    result['receiver_date'] = input_data['receiver_info']['general']['creation_date']
                    result['receiver_info'] = input_data['receiver_info']['general']['information']
                    if 'adress' in input_data['receiver_info']['general'].keys():
                        result['receiver_adress'] = input_data['receiver_info']['general']['adress']
                    else:
                        result['receiver_adress'] = ''
                    if 'two' in input_data['receiver_info']['general']['photo'].keys():
                        result['receiver_pictures'] = input_data['receiver_info']['general']['photo']['two']['ids']
                    else:
                        result['receiver_pictures'] = input_data['receiver_info']['general']['photo']['one']['ids']
                    result['receiver_stats'] = input_data['receiver_info']['command_statistics']
                    receiver_commands = []
                    if 'intrest' in input_data['receiver_info'].keys():
                        if input_data['receiver_info']['intrest']:
                            for gender in input_data['receiver_info']['intrest']['gender_type']:
                                receiver_commands.append(
                                    gender.split('/')[-1])
                                result['receiver_genders'] = receiver_commands
                    if 'receiver_photo' in input_data['receiver_info']['receiver_brand'].keys():
                        result['receiver_brand_id_photo'] = input_data[
                            'receiver_info']['receiver_brand']['receiver_photo']['id']
                    else:
                        result['receiver_brand_id_photo'] = ''
                else:
                    result['receiver_date'] = ''
                    result['receiver_adress'] = ''
                    result['receiver_stats'] = {}
                    result['receiver_pictures'] = ''
            else:
                result['receiver_date'] = ''
                result['receiver_adress'] = ''
                result['receiver_stats'] = {}
                result['receiver_pictures'] = ''
        else:
            result['receiver_date'] = ''
            result['receiver_adress'] = ''
            result['receiver_stats'] = {}
            result['receiver_pictures'] = ''
        return result
```

A small example of the `input_data`

```
input_data={
  "general": {
    "creation_date": "10/10/2015",
    "first_id": "10kahd",
    "name": "jacky",
    "information": "",
    "photo": {
      "one": {
        "ids": "1598",
      },
      "two": {
        "ids": "1489"
      },
      "tree": {
        "ids": "0298"
      }
    },
    "adress": "10,new york 159",
    "phones": [
      "number 1",
      "number 2"
    ],
    "cat": "01",
  },
  "command_details": {
    "shiping": "allowed",
  },
  "command_statistics": {
    "count": "226558",
    "items": "2015",
    "payed": "1500",
    "unpayed": "0"
  },
  "intrest": {
    "gender_type": [
      "chairs"
    ]
  },
  "cmd_id": "alsd952d",
  "receiver_info": {
    "general": {
      "name": "10,new york 159",
      "information": "",
      "creation_date": "01/06/2012",
      "photo": {
        "one": {
          "ids": "159z"
        },
        "two": {
          "ids": "98zzf"
        },
        "tree": {
          "ids": "pokAcs6"
        }
      },
    },
    "command_statistics": {
      "count": "15987643325",
      "all_cmd_count": "16549878466245",
      "all_cmd_count_years": 125,
      "sub_cmd": "1664987322"
    },
    "intrest": {
      "gender_ids": [
        "qsmplos"
      ],
      "gender_type": [
        "chairs",
        "pens"
      ]
    },
    "receiver_brand": {
      "brand_abdress": {
        "adress": "10,new york 159"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
if 'general' in input_data.keys():
    if bool(input_data['general']):
```

could be

```
if 'general' in input_data:
    if input_data['general']:
```

or even

```
if general := input_data.get('general'):
```

and then use `general` instead of repeating `input_data['general']`.

Alternatively, instead of mostly repeated statements extracting the data, you could configure the extractions as data and then use some general extraction code. Something like this (only some of the entries):

```
def general_statistics(input_data: dict):
    def genders(data):
        return [gender.split('/')[-1] for gender in data]
    config = [
        ('name', ('general', 'name'), ''),
        ('information', ('general', 'information'), ''),
        ('date', ('general', 'creation_date'), ''),
        ('adress', ('general', 'adress'), ''),
        ('picture_person', ('general', 'photo', 'one', 'ids')),
        ('picture_person', ('general', 'photo', 'two', 'ids')),
        ('phones', ('general', 'phones')),
        ('genders', ('intrest', 'gender_type', genders), []),
    ]
    result = {}
    for key, path, *default in config:
        data = input_data
        for step in path:
            if isinstance(step, str):
                if step not in data:
                    if default:
                        result[key] = default[0]
                    break
                data = data[step]
            else:
                data = step(data)
        else:
            result[key] = data
    return result
```

You might also want to use a spell checker, as your data has quite a few typos ("intrest", "tree", "adress", "shiping", "payed", "unpayed").